# Laravel 5.1 - redirect back to the base url

Tags: laravel, routes, base-url

I'm currently in my manage requests page with url `wwww.website.com/requests/manage/`. I want to redirect back to my dashboard page using `<a href="dashboard">dashborad</a>` , but when i clicked my dashboard link, the url becomes `www.website.com/requests/manage/dashboard`, Instead of `www.website.com/dashboard`

below is the code to go back to my dashboard page,

```
<td style="line-height:12pt; height:10px;">
      <a href="dashboard"><b class="brandname">
               dashboard</b>
      </a>
</td>
```

This is my routes.php file.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', 'testController@index');

    // All about buyer request...
    Route::post('requests/success', 'testController@store');
    Route::post('request/success', 'testController@store');

    Route::get('requests/new', 'testController@newRequest');
    Route::get('request/new',  'testController@newRequest');
    Route::get('requests/manage/{status?}', 'testController@manageRequest');

});
```

What i tried is add another route (see below) to fix this, but i think is not an elegant solution. any suggestions?

```
Route::get('requests/manage/dashboard', 'testController@index');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend it with a slash to create a root-relative URL.

```
<a href="/dashboard">dashboard</a>
```

You can also use helper functions like [`url`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url) to generate an absolute URL:

```
<a href="{{ url('dashboard') }}">dashboard</a>
```

The `url` helper function will create an absolute URL like `http://website.com/dashboard`.